# Javascript Regex: Replace all the matches from the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like below i want to extract the number from the string. so i have used the following regex,it is not removing the last bracket even though i have used global replace.how to write the regex so it removes all the non digit characters even it is in the beginning or in the end

[image]

Comment: Why not just use a number capture group?

Comment: Remove `^` anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex means : get the non digit from the start of the string, and end with non non digit (= digit), that's the reason your result come from.

If you want to get the number and the string's style is the same.You can use this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is what i am expecting